# json to c# deserilization

Tags: c#, php, json

I want to convert this JSON return from php file into c#. But as a newbie don't know how, please help.

```
{"response": [
    {"user_id":"26","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"},
    {"user_id":"27","crtloc_lat":"9.350192","crtloc_lng":"-95.391006"},
    {"user_id":"28","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"}
]}
```

The above JSON is returned from my PHP file.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/abh/returntest.php");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
List<Response>  json ;
using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(stream.ReadToEnd());
}
foreach (var item in json)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id={0},latitude={1},longitude={2}",item.user_id,item.crtloc_lat,item.crtloc_lng);
}
```

The Classes I am using are:

```
public class Response
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string crtloc_lat { get; set; }
    public string crtloc_lng { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[afterall.Response]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

Comment: If anyone want to check actual Php file is present at this link . [http://anybodyhere.net/returntest.php][http://anybodyhere.net/returntest.php]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is wrong based on your sample JSON.

```
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(stream.ReadToEnd());
```

Try changing it to:

```
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());
```

**Edit:**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/abh/returntest.php");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
RootObject json;
using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());
}
foreach (var item in json)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id={0},latitude={1},longitude={2}",item.user_id,item.crtloc_lat,item.crtloc_lng);
}
```

Comment: @WaqasKanju: Dietz is correct. This fixes your problem. Tested with you code and gave in the string you posted.

Comment: @WaqasKanju you have to change the declaration of the json variable aswell.

Comment: `Foreach` will not work after this edit: You have to use this  `Console.WriteLine(json.response[0].user_id);
Console.WriteLine(json.response[1].user_id);
 Console.WriteLine(json.response[2].user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the following line :

```
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(stream.ReadToEnd());
```

as

```
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(stream.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: After changing that line: it shows this error, can not implicitly convert type RootObject to System.Collection.Generics.List

Answer (score 0):

From your testlink in the comment of your post. Your response is not:

```
{"response": [
    {"user_id":"26","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"},
    {"user_id":"27","crtloc_lat":"9.350192","crtloc_lng":"-95.391006"},
    {"user_id":"28","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"}
]}
```

as you post but rather:

```
connected{"response": [
         {"user_id":"26","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"},
          {"user_id":"27","crtloc_lat":"9.350192","crtloc_lng":"-95.391006"},
          {"user_id":"28","crtloc_lat":"47.678238","crtloc_lng":"-122.131416"
          }]
    }
```

This is not corresponding to your sample code. Remove the

> connected{ }

wrapping or return correct json for a connected object (whatever the connect is). If you remove the wrapping it should work as @Dietz posted.